# Why MySql is returning time in AM instead of PM?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

When I run below query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

it return time stamp as

```
2016-09-24 05:16:53 AM
```

but it is 05:16:53 PM in my PC.

I have run below queries as well to make sure time zone is set to **SYSTEM**

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

What might be the issue? I want to retrieve 2 hours old records but due to this issue I am stuck.

Following is my query,

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NOW() < DATE_ADD(my_field_time,INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

This won't work correctly as **NOW** is 12 hours behind.

**Update:** Mysql server is on my PC, version 5.5.28, SYSTEM time zone is reported by mysql server, OS: Windows 10

Comment: Where is the mysql server? on your PC? What operating system and version of mysql are you using? what is the time zone of your PC and what is the time zone being reported by mysql? Please  edit your question with the details.

Comment: @sikander try  SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, UTC_TIMESTAMP)  and tell me what you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SET time_zone = yourtimezone //eg '+05:30'
```

After that try your query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Please note `SET time_zone = yourtimezone` will work only for the current session.

To know the difference between current datetime in your session timezone and the  current datetime in UTC,use the following query

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, UTC_TIMESTAMP)
```

If you need only specific workaround for your query as NOW is 12 hours behind,then try the query

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR < DATE_ADD(my_field_time,INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```